# Phong lighting model is not actually lighting anything

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I currently have an assignment to implement the Phong Lighting Model in openGL / GLSL. The two shaders that I am currently working with are below. The problem is that in the fragment shader, if I do not add `vColor` to `gl_FragColor` then the entire shape is black. However, if I DO add `vColor`, then the entire shape is that color with no lighting at all. I have been trying to solve this for a couple of hours now to no luck. What is the reason for this? Is it a problem in my shaders, or a problem perhaps in the openGL code? I am using one material and one point light source, which I'll show after the shaders.

Edit: If I set `gl_FragColor = vec4(N, 1.0)` then the object looks like this:

[image]

vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec4 vPosition;
in vec3 vNormal;

uniform mat4 vMatrix;
uniform vec4 LightPosition;

out vec3 fNorm;
out vec3 fEye;
out vec3 fLight;

void main() {
  fNorm = vNormal;
  fEye = vPosition.xyz;
  fLight = LightPosition.xyz;

  if(LightPosition.w != 0.0) {
    fLight = LightPosition.xyz - vPosition.xyz;
  }

gl_Position = vMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 fNorm;
in vec3 fLight;
in vec3 fEye;

uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform vec4 AmbientProduct, DiffuseProduct, SpecularProduct;
uniform mat4 vMatrix;
uniform vec4 LightPosition;
uniform float Shininess;

void main(){
    vec3 N = normalize(fNorm);
    vec3 E = normalize(fEye);
    vec3 L = normalize(fLight);
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);

    vec4 ambient = AmbientProduct;

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * DiffuseProduct;

    float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), Shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks * SpecularProduct;
    if(dot(L,N) < 0.0) 
        specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 

    gl_FragColor = vColor + ambient + diffuse + specular;
}
```

Setting materials and light:

```
void init() {

    setMaterials(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), //ambient
             vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0), //diffuse
             vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), //specular
             100.0); //shine

    setLightSource(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), //ambient
               vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), //diffuse
               vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), //specular
               vec4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0)); //position

    setProducts();

    ....
}

/*
 * Sets the material properties for Phong lighting model.
 */
void setMaterials(vec4 amb, vec4 dif, vec4 spec, GLfloat s) {
    ambient = amb;
    diffuse = dif;
    specular = spec;
    shine = s;

    glUniform1f(vShininess, shine);
}

/*
 * Set light source properties.
 */
void setLightSource(vec4 amb, vec4 dif, vec4 spec, vec4 pos) {
    ambient0 = amb;
    diffuse0 = dif;
    specular0 = spec;
    light0_pos = pos;

    glUniform4fv(vLightPosition, 1, light0_pos);
}

/*
 * Find the products of materials components and light components.
 */
void setProducts(){
    vec4 ambientProduct = ambient * ambient0;
    vec4 diffuseProduct = diffuse * diffuse0;
    vec4 specularProduct = specular * specular0;

    glUniform4fv(vAmbientProduct, 1, ambientProduct);
    glUniform4fv(vDiffuseProduct, 1, diffuseProduct);
    glUniform4fv(vSpecularProduct, 1, specularProduct);

}
```

Comment: after your edit it seems clear that the normals appear to be wrong. Have you tried using the shader on something very simple like a plane with its normals just pointing up or one of the glut primitives?

Comment: You need to start debugging through the possibilities. First, just make sure that your lighting uniforms are coming through correctly by writing those directly out to the screen. Like `gl_FragColor = ambient` and so forth. Then ensure that the normals you get are reasonable by writing those out as color values. Then, see what dot(N, L) is by writing that. And so on, until you find the part that stops making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final lighting composition doesn't look right:

> ```
> gl_FragColor = vColor + ambient + diffuse + specular;
> ```

It should be something like

```
gl_FragColor = vColor * (ambient + diffuse) + specular;
```

i.e. the illumination modulated by the albedo of the object.